# React native button icon position issue

Tags: react-native

I created button with TouchableOpacity and LinearGradient that has icon with text inside and I want to set icon to be near start of button and text in center. I tried to set margin property for icon but then text also moves with icon. Can someone please help me to fix this?

```
const Button = ({ title, btnStyle, onPress, linearGradient, iconName }) =>
{
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.btn}
            onPress={onPress}
        >
            <LinearGradient
                start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
                end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
                colors={["#00c6ff", "#0072ff"]}
                style={[styles.imageView, btnStyle]}>
                <FontAwesome5 name="facebook-f" style={{ fontSize: 35 }} color="#ffffff" />
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{title}</Text>
            </LinearGradient>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create(
{
    buttonText:
    {
        fontSize: 18,
        textAlign: "center",
        margin: 10,
        color: "#ffffff",
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        padding: 5
    },
    linearGradient:
    {
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginBottom: "15%",
        height: 60
    },
    btn:
    {
        borderRadius: 5,
        height: 60,
        marginVertical: 10,
        marginHorizontal: 15,
        paddingVertical: 50
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 const Button = ({ title, btnStyle, onPress, linearGradient, iconName }) =>
    {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.btn}
                onPress={onPress}
            >
                <LinearGradient
                    start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
                    end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
                    colors={["#00c6ff", "#0072ff"]}
                    style={[styles.imageView, linearGradient]}>
                    <FontAwesome5 name="facebook-f" style={{ fontSize: 35, flex: 0.10,textAlign:'right',  }} color="#ffffff" />
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{title}</Text>
                </LinearGradient>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    };

    const styles = StyleSheet.create(
    {
        buttonText:
        {
             flex: 0.9,
             justifyContent: "center",
             alignItems: "center",
             fontSize: 18,
             textAlign: "center",
             color: "#ffffff",
             backgroundColor: "transparent",

        },
        linearGradient:
        {
             flex: 1,
             flexDirection: "row",
             justifyContent: "flex-start",
             alignItems: "center",
             borderRadius: 5,
             height: 60,
        },
        btn:
        {
            flex:1,
            borderRadius: 5,
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried your code but button doesn't appear on screen then

Comment: Hi @Albert, I have attached the screenshot of button do you need button like that?
https://imgur.com/Gnbk23s. Let me know I'll update the answer. 
Thanks.

Comment: Yes I need button like that

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed flex value for text to 0.8 to make it more centered.

Comment: @Albert my pleasure :)